# Akka Config - application.conf - Setting Dispatcher & Router

Tags: java, akka

In Akka 2.2.0 I have a round robin routed Actor which I want to have a custom dispatcher sitting over.

In my `application.conf` I have;

```
durable-dispatcher {
  mailbox-type = akka.actor.mailbox.filebased.FileBasedMailboxType
}

akka.actor.deployment {
  /notificationServiceWorkers {
    dispatcher = durable-dispatcher
    router = round-robin
    nr-of-instances = 5
  }
}
```

Now when I try to create this actor like so;

```
ActorRef notificationServiceWorkers = akka.actorOf(Props.create(NotificationServiceActor.class)
   .withRouter(new FromConfig()), "notificationServiceWorkers")
```

The dispatcher is not picked up from the config and it uses the default dispatcher.

If I remove the `.withRouter`, Akka picks up the config for the dispatcher just fine but obviously its no longer routed.

If I add the `.withDispatcher` like so;

```
ActorRef notificationServiceWorkers = akka.actorOf(Props.create(NotificationServiceActor.class)
       .withDispatcher("durable-dispatcher")
       .withRouter(new FromConfig()), "notificationServiceWorkers")
```

It all works. The question is (its not clear from the doco) if I want to load a dispatcher and router configuration from the *application.conf* then why do I need to supply both in the Props creation? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why your deployment is not picked up is that the routees are created as children of the router, hence they live at paths `notificationServiceWorkers/*`.

Answer (score 3):

In taking an in depth look at the Akka code inside `LocalActorRefProvider`, you can see inside of the `actorOf` that they only take the dispatcher from the deployment config if it's a non-routed actor.  I imagine they have their reasons for this, but what it means for you is that if you are going to use a router and you want a different dispatcher (other than the default dispatcher), you will need to use the `withDispatcher` explicitly on the `Props` instance and you will not be able to get it from the config.  Again, I don't know if this is a bug, but from the looks of their code, it appears they intentionally do not pull from the config when it's a routed actor.

Comment: That's great. Thanks cmbaxter. I think this is intended functionality too. Interested to know why though.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to Roland Kuhn's answer, this is working:

```
"/notificationServiceWorkers/*" {
  dispatcher = durable-dispatcher
}
```